# Additional checks in hash.each

Tags: ruby

I have a code:

```
c = "SMTHLKKK"
b = {
  "lol1" => {
     "lol21" => {"lol3" => "smth"},
     "lol22" => {"lol3" => "smth"},
     "lol2" => {"lol3" => "smth"}
  }
}
```

I want to check if `c` exists, and if it does, I want to set the values for `"lol3"` in the nested hashes in `b` to `"SMTHLKKK"`. Otherwise, I set it to `"SMT"`. I want to check whether `key != "lol22` in each block before setting the value.

I tried this:

```
b["lol1"].each{|key, value| value["lol3"] = c ? c : "SMT"}
```

How can I do this check?

Comment: `c` is `"SMTHLKKK"`, and that has never changed after the assignment in your code. Hence, `c` **always** exists. Your issue does not seem to make sense.

Comment: It's just an example. In real code in some cases c doesn't exist

Answer (score 2):

You should steer towards writing methods that encapsulate this sort of thing than just throwing together some code. It helps organize things better and expresses your intent more clearly. For example:

```
require 'set'

DEFAULT_DEFAULT = 'SMT'

def fill_with_defaults(hash, default = nil, skip_keys = nil)
  default ||= DEFAULT_DEFAULT
  skip_keys ||= Set.new(skip_keys || [ ])

  hash.each do |key, sub|
    next if (skip_keys.include?(key))

    sub['lol3'] = default
  end

  hash
end
```

Where here there's a well-defined method called `fill_with_defaults` that takes three arguments, the hash, the default to set and the keys to skip.

The default is assigned a default if it's not specified and the keys to skip are converted to a Set for performance reasons, this helps with larger arrays. You could even force that argument to be a set in the first place if you're calling this more frequently on smaller hashes instead of fewer times on larger hashes. There's trade-offs in both directions.

The set allows you to quickly skip any unnecessary keys, and the default is set once to avoid repeated `||` checks.

Then you can use it like this:

```
fill_with_defaults(b['lol1'], 'SMTHLKK', %w[ lol2 ])
```

Where that'll skip the `lol2` key.

Comment: Thx a lot) But my purpose was not in writing good code but to write code with several checks in one ( or two) lines. I know that it's wrong and etc, but very interesting for me.

Comment: @grenfunday Don't forget clarity trumps brevity. Your clever one-liner solutions might seem interesting today but if two years from now you need to fix one of them you might be cursing about your old habits.